# VPN PPTP problems

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint, pptp

Followed the tutorials in the net and all led me to this same problem everytime. Am i missing something? Tried first with GUI and then i attempted to configure VPN with terminal.

```
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1553861774.7094] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1553861774.7094] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1553861774.7133] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pppd[6376]: Using interface ppp0
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pppd[6376]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF systemd-udevd[6467]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1553861774.7202] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/74)
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pptp[6468]: anon log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pptp[6468]: anon warn[pptp_gre_bind:pptp_gre.c:102]: socket: Operation not permitted
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pptp[6468]: anon fatal[main:pptp.c:360]: Cannot bind GRE socket, aborting.
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pppd[6376]: Modem hangup
Mar 29 12:16:14 rubenq-X556UF pppd[6376]: Connection terminated.
```

Comment: Don't use PPTP. PPTP is broken (insecure) and has been deprecated for many years. Use any other VPN protocol.

Comment: i must use it to connect to my university vpn. its not my choice...